# Extend Formula Range Using Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel-2010, excel-interop

I'm using the Excel Interop libraries to take a sheet and replace values in the sheet. My sheet structure is as follows:

Columns A-E contain formula which work off the data in Columns F-L
When I update the sheet, I clear the contents from F-L and leave any formula in A-E. I then fill columns F-L with new data.

I need my formula in Columns A-E(any rows) to extend to the full range of the new data I entered.

For example `=sum(G1,G8)` should become `=sum(G1,G20)` if I extend the data to 20 rows from 8.
Is there a way to get to all present formula in the sheet? How do I extend the range of the formula?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While inputting data to the cells, keep track of each new cell and then apply the formula to that range:

```
sheet.Cells[rowCount, column].Formula = string.Format("=SUM(G1:G{0})", rowCount);
```

Comment: Looks like you might be missing a `)` at the end of your format. `"=SUM(G1,G{0})"`

Comment: @SwDevMan81 nice spot. Amended.

Comment: That's what I was thinking - But I was hoping there was an easier way, since they can really have any formula(although they must be rows 1 to max). I'll be using this method and then regex I guess?

Comment: @Byron Cobb Not that I know of I'm afraid. Are the formulas not predefined? (A1 will always have =SUM(), B1 will always have =RAND() etc)

Comment: @SeeSharp - Nope, the users define the formula, we just update the data and their formula range. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Byron Cobb I see, I see.. I've not done anything with it, but there's the `Change` event on the worksheet - could maybe set its range for the whole worksheet and update the formulas like that?

Comment: Awesome - just what the Arzt ordered.

Answer (score 0):

For information on manipulating the Excel object mode, I'd recommend looking first for a VBA solution, then converting this to C# (which is trivial).  There are far more VBA resources available on the web, and you can sometimes even help yourself by recording a VBA macro.

Depending on exactly where your formulae are, you may be able to achieve what you want by inserting rows.

E.g. if you have a formula in, say, A3 that references the range G1:G8, and you now want to insert twenty rows of data instead of 8, you can move row 8 down 20-8 = 12 times as follows before writing your data.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim nIndex As Long
Set rng = Rows("8:8")
For nIndex = 1 To 20 - 8
    rng.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Next nIndex
```

When you do this, the formula in A3 will be modified automatically to include the inserted rows.

Note that doing this via Interop will not be particularly efficient for a large number of rows (a round trip from your app to the Excel process for each row inserted).  One way to improve performance is to insert multiple rows at a time.

Comment: This looks like it's just shifting a range down. I need to modify any formula's range and not just a simple range G1:G20. I'm looking to have sum(G1:G20) or max(G1:G20) or concatenate(G1:G20), etc.. for every formula nested or not.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to parse the object to Range...

```
(((Excel.Range))yourWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, column]).Formula = string.Format("=SUM(G1,G{0})", rowCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but with IF formula. Setting it to Formula property didn't work. However the same works if set to FormulaLocal...

thanks Microsoft :)

btw: Formula and FormulaLocal will work only for A1 [reference style](http://www.lytebyte.com/2008/04/29/what-are-a1-and-r1c1-reference-style-in-excel/). For R1C1 you should use FormulaR1C1 and FormulaR1C1Local.